# Android Webview looking poor quality than system browser

Tags: android, webview

I have developed a webview in android application which renders existing web application. I considered target sdk as 8. After development application works perfect in Samsung devices(ICS) but when I test the same in my Asus(ICS) tablet the quality is very poor, everything looks blurred whereas the same looks perfect when i test in it's system browser.

Any relation to hardware? please suggest me some way..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the `minSDK level to 11.` and enable hardware Acceleration in the application `manifest` at `application level`.